# HDCP with Mac Mini and an external monitor

Tags: catalina, hdcp

If I attempt to play movies on the TV app or Disney+ through the browser I am getting the following error:

[image: HDCP Error]

This is with a newish LG 5K monitor connected to a 2018 MacMini via Thunderbolt.

Interestingly Disney+ works fine if I reboot into Windows via Bootcamp which tends to indicate the hardware is OK.

Comment: Which exact monitor is it?

Comment: Apple TV requires HDCP, you probably need to use HDMI instead of Thunderbolt.

Comment: LG UltraFine 5K - 27MD5KL-B

Comment: @jaume The monitor doesn't support HDMI.

Comment: The Mac Mini has an HDMI port (as per https://support.apple.com/kb/SP782), so now you need an adapter Thunderbolt 2 <-> HDMI that explicitly supports HDCP,  maybe something like this: ANOXY MDP-HDMI Mini Display Port to HDMI Adapter with HDCP Support (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004OAQDFS/ref=dp_prsubs_3)

Comment: That adapter won't work because it is a Thunderbolt 3 port.

Answer (score 1):

@jaume was correct, you want to use an HDMI cable if possible.

[More information about High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection (HDCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection)

Comment: The monitor doesn't support HDMI.

Comment: That's an issue.  The content that you are playing has some digital protections on it. It will not play on an external device if it can't securely send that content over the wires. 

You can read about HDCP here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection

Comment: There is nothing on that page that says Thunderbolt doesn't support HDCP.